Кастомизация графиков в Vue 3 используя библиотеку vue-chartjs
Не могу понять как работает кастомизация графика в данной либе, даже в их песочнице пытаюсь изменить цвет линии или избавится от точек на графике. но все тщетно.
пример кода
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/apertureless/vue-chartjs/tree/v4/legacy/sandboxes/line?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FLine.vue%3A96%2C35&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5u0006356jyhcekh2c%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5t0002356jk8ac6hnq%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5t0003356jf3lwlva3%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5t0005356jdj2qgf04%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clupgsc5t0002356jk8ac6hnq%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5t0001356js7wpxaeq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cluphhebt0037356jimelyb3r%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A96%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A35%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A96%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A35%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FLine.vue%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5t0002356jk8ac6hnq%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cluphhebt0037356jimelyb3r%2522%257D%252C%2522clupgsc5t0005356jdj2qgf04%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5t0004356j9dcbwquv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5t0005356jdj2qgf04%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5t0004356j9dcbwquv%2522%257D%252C%2522clupgsc5t0003356jf3lwlva3%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clupgsc5t0003356jf3lwlva3%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D
